# Creating a connection between to tables in many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: `photos (id,path)` and `tags(id,name)`.
Tables are in many-to-many relationship, so I've got a third table:
`photos_tags(photos_id, tags_id)`.

Now, how can I connect a photo of specified path with tag of specified name?
I'd like to do something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO photos_tags
  SELECT photos.id, tags.id FROM photos, tags
  WHERE photos.path = '/some/path' AND tags.name = 'tag';
```

Comment: I don't know about SQLite specifically, but the insert statement you posted is valid SQL. If SQLite requires SQL:1999 syntax, you may need to change the from clause to `photos cross join tags`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into photos_tags
(photos_id, tags_id)
select id,
    (
        select id
        from Tags
        where name = 'tag'
        )
from photos
where path = '/some/path'
```

Comment: Won't that throw an error if the sub-query returns more than one row?

Comment: @weenoid No, it won't. It will insert multiple rows in that case, which I think is the desired result.

Comment: Does that mean that the following SQL is valid: SELECT 1, ( SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 )

Comment: @weenoid Sorry, misunderstood, yes that would cause an error. If that can happen, a TOP 1 can be added. Usually you would put a unique index on a tags names column.